# Get the data from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I'm using visual web developer C#, I set the `storeid` to default value of 100 from Sql Server. 
I then set the column `storeid` to visible false cause I want to automatically insert 100 without showing on my form. But every time I try inserting a new record from my form it only shows null in the database `storeid` column.

This is the `storeid` datagridview column code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store ID" 
SortExpression="StoreID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
```

This is the storeid details view code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store ID" 
 SortExpression="StoreID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" ReadOnly="Visible="False">
```

This is my storeid column database:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StaffCCD] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_StaffCCD_StoreID]  DEFAULT ((100)) FOR [StoreID]
```

Comment: Not that I think it's causing the problem but in the second code listing you have a syntax error "ReadOnly="Visible"False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is even though the column is hidden, a value of 'Null' for StoreID is still being passed in the Insert. A default constraint will only work when [no other value](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) is supplied for the column.

I'd test the default value is correctly configured by running an insert statement (without setting Store ID) in SQL Management Studio and checking that Store ID is in fact defaulting correctly to 100.

Comment: so what should i do to show the data with default 100 to the database from the form?

Comment: From the code above, it looks like you're hidding the store ID in both the column and the view. Why don't you just remove it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using some kind of Data Source Control and binding your GridView to that? And I'm also assuming you've chosen to auto generate the insert, update and delete statements? If this is the case what you can try is to manually configure the insert statement when by selecting the "Specify a custome SQL Statement or Stored Procedure" option (This is available in the SQL DataSource Control). You then need to make sure that StoreID is not present in the insert. If you need help, you can use the Query Builder functionality to generate the necessary SQL Statement.

Comment: Mr. Damon, It works, Thank You But i have a new problem. See i need to export my table to csv. I removed the sql statement that u said so now when i click the export button it should show the columns StoreID, Date, EmpID, StartTime, EndTime. But now its only showing the Date, EmpID, StartTime, EndTime.

Comment: Good stuff Mr. Paul ;) Remember to keep the StoreID in the Select statement then you can then still bind it in the grid (and export it). It's only necessary to exclude it from the insert statement (and maybe the update). Also, just a word of warning...don't include blocks of code in comments, it's not good practise on this site.

Comment: Oh and Paul, if I've help solve this problem, feel free to mark this as answered. It'll just let others know it's been answered (and give me some much needed rep haha!)